# align badges to the right in github README using Markdown

Tags: badge, github-flavored-markdown, fdroid

am translating a github readme file from English to Arabic,
while doing that i faced a problem where i can't algin this following badge form the left to the rghit

```
[<img src="https://fdroid.gitlab.io/artwork/badge/get-it-on-ar.png"
     alt="Get it on F-Droid"
     height="70">](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.junkfood.seal/)
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<div align= "right"></div>` like this:

```html
<div align="right">
  [<img src="https://fdroid.gitlab.io/artwork/badge/get-it-on-ar.png" style="text-align: right" alt="Get it on F-Droid" height="70">](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.junkfood.seal/)
</div>
```